# Unable to establish data center in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I was following [Initializing a multiple node cluster (single datacenter)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html)
:

`cassandra.yaml` i did below changes :

```
- seeds: "192.168.1.8, localhost"
- endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
- rpc_address: localhost
```

All other changes are default. I did the same changes on two different laptop connected through the same wifi.

When i run `bin/nodetool status` I see just one entry:

```
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  146.15 KiB  256          100.0%            b13a2e35-5228-43f7-8e3e-667685fc771e  rack1
```

I run cassandra as `bin/cassandra -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true` and here is the log:

```
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:14,869 IndexSummaryManager.java:85 - Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 96 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:14,877 MessagingService.java:753 - Starting Messaging Service on localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 (lo)
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:14,899 OutboundTcpConnection.java:108 - OutboundTcpConnection using coalescing strategy DISABLED
WARN  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:45,926 Gossiper.java:1417 - Unable to gossip with any seeds but continuing since node is in its own seed list
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:45,947 StorageService.java:706 - Loading persisted ring state
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:45,948 StorageService.java:819 - Starting up server gossip
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:04:46,433 StorageService.java:857 - This node will not auto bootstrap because it is configured to be a seed node.
```

If i run without `bin/cassandra -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true` i am getting this:

```
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:24:40,303 StorageService.java:819 - Starting up server gossip
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:24:40,769 TokenMetadata.java:479 - Updating topology for localhost/127.0.0.1
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:24:40,771 TokenMetadata.java:479 - Updating topology for localhost/127.0.0.1
INFO  [main] 2018-07-15 18:24:40,822 StorageService.java:1442 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
```

Comment: whats a problem?

Comment: `bin/nodetool status` should show two entry right if all good?

Comment: try  setting: Node 1: seeds = node1,node2 Node 2: seeds = node2.

Comment: it didnt work..

Answer (score 0):

I would update:

- on the seeds list from localhost to the internal IP address of the node,
- also set the same IP as above as listen_address.
- then add the external IP address of the node to broadcast_address and
- finally set rcp_address to 0.0.0.0